# With 'hg record', is there a way to automatically look at all changes in all files?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

`hg record` is very useful for splitting the changes in your working copy into multiple commits.

When you run `hg record`, it will ask you for each modified file:

```
examine changes to '<file>'? [Ynesfdaq?]
```

and if you say yes, then for each change in the file:

```
record change X/Y to '<file>'? [Ynesfdaq?]
```

However, I often find that I could complete the operation much more efficiently by automatically being shown all changes (i.e. as if I said `y` to every question of the first form). Basically, I want to see all changed hunks and make yes/no decisions about them, without the distraction of intervening `examine changes to <file>?` questions (to which I would always say yes).

Is there to get `hg record` way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the [CRecord Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CrecordExtension) invaluable for this. It gives a curses based UI for the record command, and allows you to get a much better overview of all your changes. It also allows you to select down to line resolution, rather than just each hunk.

Comment: That's an awesome extension! I'm never going back to plain `record` :)